# EJS res.render() returning a 500 server error after logging in

Tags: node.js, express, routes, ejs

I'm trying to build a simple RSVP app for my wedding, and I am starting to implement a login functionality to hide certain pages like the RSVP form for our invitees and the guest list page for me and my fiancee (admins).

I'm having issues when it comes to redirecting to the guest list page after authenticating the user.

I've tried rendering other pages that exist in my view, and they work. Even directly loading the guest-list page works. It's rendering it after logging in that doesn't.

```
http://localhost:3000/guest-list
```

Below is my form for logging in. I have a register page that I've verified correctly stores the username/password to my usersTable in mongodb

```
          <form action="/admin-login" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <input type="username" class="form-control" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Login</button>
          </form>
```

And below is code in my **app.js** that handles the routing. The console.log() you see before the res.render() works as it should.

```
app.post("/admin-login", function(req,res){
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, foundUser){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
          if(foundUser){
            if(foundUser.password === password){
              console.log("user: " + foundUser.username);
              res.render("guest-list");
            }
          }
    }
  });
});
```

The expected result is that I should be redirected to the guest-list page. But I am getting a server 500 error and this message:

```
{"error":{"path":"C:\\My Websites\\rsvp-app\\views\\guest-list.ejs"}}
```

I'm registering the views for ejs like this:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: So, `res.render()` is telling you that it isn't finding a `guest-list.ejs` file in the views directory.  The error is spelled out pretty cleanly.  Apparently that file does not exist in that directory.  Actually, it looks like this may be a backslash problem in your Javascript path strings and that's why it can't find `guest-list.ejs`.  Please show us the code where you register the views directory for ejs.

Comment: I also notice that there are all sorts of paths through your `/admin-login` route handler that do not return any response.  That's bad.  You should always be returning some sort of response, even if just `res.sendStatus(500)` to signify an internal error.

Comment: jfriend00, thanks for responding! I've edited the post to include your suggestion of including how I'm registering views for ejs. The weird thing is that when i go to the guest-list page directly, it's loading fine. It acts weird when i render it after logging in.  Could you clarify the backlash problem in path strings you were talking about?

Comment: Well, the double backslashes in `"C:\\My Websites\\rsvp-app\\views\\guest-list.ejs"` look wrong to me unless that's just a console side effect.  You can step into `res.render()` in the debugger and see how it's forming the path for your file and see exactly where it fails and that will probably shed some light on why.

Comment: Ah I read it as 'backlash'. Yeah, the backslashes does seem odd. i'm rendering it as any other page that I have. What's weirder is that when I try to render other pages that I have in the same directory, they load fine. Hyphens shouldn't have any effect right?

i'll debug the ```res.render()```

Comment: So, I think I know what the problem is. In my earlier lines of code in my app.js, I am rendering the guest-list page with some data to display. Now in my ```admin-login``` code, I'm trying to render it without passing in any data, I tried to use ```res.redirect('guest-list')``` and it works. Is there any downside to using res.redirect as opposed to res.render() in this scenario?

Comment: `res.redirect("/guest-list")` is probably better because then the URL bar in the browser will show `http://whatever.com/guest-list` instead of the URL of the form you posted from.  No downside I'm aware of.

Comment: jfriend00, thank you for all your input!